# Calculating the right number of workgroups and their size OpenCL

Tags: c, opencl

I'm new with OpenCL and I'm trying to understand this example program written by Apple [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/OpenCL_Hello_World_Example/Listings/hello_c.html).

The goal of the program is to calculate the square of each element of an input array and write the result in a new array.

You can see that the input array has dimension: 1024. The number of work groups is 1024 and the size of each of those is the max CL_KERNEL_WORK_GROUP_SIZE.

Can anybody explain me what's the point of using so many work-items in each work group if in the Kernel there's no get_local_id() call? Could they use 1 as the size of each work group? what would have been the difference?

Thanks.

Some code to show the point:

```
    // Get the maximum work group size for executing the kernel on the device
    //
    err = clGetKernelWorkGroupInfo(kernel, device_id, CL_KERNEL_WORK_GROUP_SIZE, sizeof(local), &local, NULL);


    // Execute the kernel over the entire range of our 1d input data set
    // using the maximum number of work group items for this device
    //
    global = count;
    err = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(commands, kernel, 1, NULL, &global, &local, 0, NULL, NULL);
```

Comment: This is not CUDA, size is not local*global, is just global. Global size is what matters, the kernel code is run that amount of times. The local size is only useful when you want to share information on the running items and has to divide the global size. For example share some data between items 0-1023. If you don't share data at all, then the size is no t really important, but higher sizes are prefered due to reduction in overheads and increase in device occupation.

Comment: @DarkZeros  Ok I got it, global size matters in that case, so local_work_size in clEnqueueNDRangeKernel call could be 1 or NULL, and nothing would change practically, right?

Comment: Yes thats it. And that is the reason why OpenCL allows local size  to be NULL, therefore the driver selects the size it thinks is best for performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your global work size is executed in chunks of local work size (in theory), if you set 1 as your local work group size, then it would execute only 1 thread in each local work group. On GPUs, work groups match to compute units - if you have a work group size of 1, your 1 thread may potentially occupy a whole compute unit. This is really, really horribly slow

Comment: so executing code on a GPU using 1 work-item per work-group is faster than executing the same code on a CPU of course, but you can still improve by doing more work in the work-group increasing the number of work-items. Is this correct?

Comment: the point is: if I increase the number of work-items in the example by apple I won't get better result in terms of efficiency, since I'm not using local memory. right?

Comment: 1 work-item per work-group is probably slower than using a CPU. GPU's have something like 32 compute cores, so 1 work-item per work group likely means only 32 'threads' running at once, which is extremely slow. Increasing the work group size will drastically increase performance - gpus use the per-workgroup threads to run waves, which fill the SIMD resources on a GPU and allow you to get memory in coalesced accesses. If you only used 1 thread per core, you'd drastically underutilise these resources

Comment: Potentially, but the thread size apple gets is the 'optimum' thread size for *that* kernel I believe. Also, its important to remember local memory isn't a silver bullet - more local memory can reduce kernel occupancy (number of active wavefronts), which in *itself* is a confusing statistic (high occupancy good for memory bound kernels, low occupancy can apparently be good for arithmetic bound kernels due to caching). So, a higher work-group size (with more local memory usage) isn't necessarily better. There's also a cap on the size of a workgroup 1024ish for nvidia, 256/512ish for amd

Comment: This is the clarification I needed. It's clear now. Thank you.